# CloudFormation !Select with !Split function with load balancer arn

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, nlb, aws-elb

I am trying to create cloudwatch alarm for Network ELB using cloudformation template. I am using Select function with the combination of split function to fetch require element.

NLB:-
`arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:123456:loadbalancer/net/dev-nlb-3HGD5SO64D/7GL51FD3`

NLBTargetGroup:-
`arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:123456:targetgroup/dev-nlb-2A6W3JC4R/9DH34SJY`

```
  Alarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      ActionsEnabled: True
      AlarmDescription: test alarm
      ComparisonOperator:  GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      Dimensions:
        - Name: LoadBalancer
          Value: !Select ["5", !Split [":", !Ref NLB]]
        - Name: TargetGroup
          Value: !Select ["5", !Split [":", !Ref NLBTargetGroup]]
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      MetricName: HealthyHostCount
      Namespace: AWS/NetworkELB
      AlarmActions:
        - arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:123456:TestSNS
      OKActions:
        - arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:123456:TestSNS
      Period: 60
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: 2.0
      TreatMissingData: missing
```

With the above config, I am able to select value for "TargetGroup" as "targetgroup/dev-nlb-2A6W3JC4R/9DH34SJY" but for "LoadBalancer" value is getting as "loadbalancer/net/dev-nlb-3HGD5SO64D/7GL51FD3".
My aim is to get only "**net/dev-nlb-3HGD5SO64D/7GL51FD3**"

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it using for [NLB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html#aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer-return-values):

```
!GetAtt YourNLB.LoadBalancerFullName
```

and for [target group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup.html#aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup-return-values):

```
!GetAtt YourTG.TargetGroupFullName
```

Thus you can do:

```
      Dimensions:
        - Name: LoadBalancer
          Value: !GetAtt YourNLB.LoadBalancerFullName
        - Name: TargetGroup
          Value: !GetAtt YourTG.TargetGroupFullName
```

In case you really need to split the string, for NLB, your Split-Join combo would be:

```
 Value: !Join
      - '/'
      - - !Select [1, !Split [ '/', !Select ["5", !Split [":", !Ref NLB]]]]
        - !Select [2, !Split [ '/', !Select ["5", !Split [":", !Ref NLB]]]]
        - !Select [3, !Split [ '/', !Select ["5", !Split [":", !Ref NLB]]]]
```

and for TargetGroup:

```
  Value: !Join
    - '/'
    - - !Select [1, !Split [ '/', !Select ["5", !Split [":", !Ref NLBTargetGroup]]]]
      - !Select [2, !Split [ '/', !Select ["5", !Split [":", !Ref NLBTargetGroup]]]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much folks for your inputs. Initially, I tried using "Join" function but ended up getting error 'Fn::Select  cannot select nonexistent value at index 5'.
I have then used '!GetAtt YourNLB.LoadBalancerFullName' which solved my problem.

Comment: @SagarJadhav No problem. Glad it worked out. Acceptance of either answer would be appreciated if helpful. Otherwise your question will appear as unanswered for others.

Answer (score 2):

**If** these resources are in the same CloudFormation stack as your alarm you can actually use the below functionality to get the names of both of these resources:

- `!GetAtt: NLB.LoadBalancerFullName`
- `!GetAtt: NLBTargetGroup.TargetGroupFullName`

For your stack this would become

```
  Alarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      ActionsEnabled: True
      AlarmDescription: test alarm
      ComparisonOperator:  GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      Dimensions:
        - Name: LoadBalancer
          Value: NLB.LoadBalancerFullName
        - Name: TargetGroup
          Value: NLBTargetGroup.TargetGroupFullName
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      MetricName: HealthyHostCount
      Namespace: AWS/NetworkELB
      AlarmActions:
        - arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:123456:TestSNS
      OKActions:
        - arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:123456:TestSNS
      Period: 60
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: 2.0
      TreatMissingData: missing
```

If this is part of a nested stack you can of course also use these values as [output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html).

Otherwise if these are part of a separate stack (and not nested stack) and you're simply copying these values in (or referencing from an export) you would need to perform multiple splits to retrieve the information you're looking for.